# In MySQL ib_buffer_pool and ibtmp1 also moved when migrated system tablespace ibdata file

Tags: mysql, innodb

We are using latest version of MySQL 8.0.20. I have moved the System Tablespace ibdata1 data file to a separate filesystem.
I have noticed the ib_buffer_pool and ibtmp1 files have also moved.

How come?

Comment: Those files will be recreated when you start the server and they dont exist. Also, the data directory is to be copied completely. If you copy only parts of it, you may severely corrupt your database.

Comment: I necessary don't agree with your statement that I need to copy the data directory completely. All I am doing is segregating System Tablespace with Files_per_Table Tablespaces. Our data size is about 8TB, so you mean to say I have to copy all or None?